# There is no group whose quotient by the center is isomorphic to the quaternion group

Tags: group-theory, quaternions

I have to prove that there is no group $G$ such that $G/Z(G)$ is isomorphic to $Q_8$.

Anytone can give me an idea to begin? thanks

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let $i,j$ be generators of $Q_8$. Then $-1$ belongs to $\langle x\rangle$ for $x\in \{i,j\} $.

Comment: Use this together with the fact that if $H\le Z(G)$ and $G/H$ is cyclic, then $G$ must be abelian. The details are in Hagen von Eitzen's answer in the linke thread.